# How to use Riverpod .family providers to watch single items of a list of data objects?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

When using Riverpod trying to watch a list of Objects and having a family provider to simultaniously watch single elements inside the list, we are not able to keep the objects consistent while adhering to Riverpods immutability constraints.

Say in our Flutter app we want to display a list (or any kind of Iterable) of items which are of a model class like:

```
class DataObject {
  final String name;
  int number;

  DataObject(this.name, this.number);
}
```

Now we have created a riverpod provider to maintain the state of the list of items:

```
@riverpod
class CounterList extends _$CounterList {
  @override
  List<DataObject> build() {
    return [];
  }

  void addCounter(DataObject dataObject) {
    state = [...state, dataObject];
  }

  void increment(String name) {
    state = [
      for (final counter in state)
        if (counter.name == name) DataObject(name, counter.number + 1) else counter
    ];
  }
}
```

This works so far, but when we display the list, we don't want to redraw the whole list when a single element changes, which is why we added a family Provider:

```
@riverpod
class CounterFamily extends _$CounterFamily {
  @override
  DataObject build(
    String name, {
    DataObject? obj,
  }) {
    return ref.watch(counterListProvider).firstWhere((dataObj) => dataObj.name == name);
  }

  void increment() {
    state = DataObject(state.name, state.number + 7);
  }
}
```

Now we can change single elements without having to redraw the entire list. Great.

However: because we create a new DataObject in the increment method of the family provider (i think we have to in order to adhere to riverpods immutability constraints) the objects maintained in the list provider and the single objects watched via the Family Provider are not the same anymore. Which of course is a nightmare in respect to coherent state management.

Question:
How can we consistently manage the state of multiple instances of the same dataObject ? With the following requirements:

- any sort of Iterable to store all elements of dataObject
- tracking the state of the Iterable to get notified upon eg adds and removes
- simultaniously track the state of the single objects to prevent redrawing of the whole list whenever a single object changes (redrawing the whole list everytime a single object changes leads to performance issues with our actual bigger dataObjects)
- the tracked single objects should be the actual objects inside the list. we do not want to create new objects, because that would effectively go against coherent state.

Answer (score 0):

How about you do not increase the state number inside the CounterFamily? Do it inside the CounterList. When you do that, CounterFamily, which watches CounterList, will update automatically too.

If you have trouble with deep copying and increasing the state number while you do so, flutter **freezed** package comes in handy.